# Applying filters to the_content() to separate content if any `add_shortcode()` is found?

Tags: shortcode

I don't even know if this possible, with `array_map` or `str_replace`, but the idea is the follow:

This function gets the content and before is sent out, `clean_custom_content`, there is where i cant figure out how to procede.. so lets assume that we have all the content, this content it will be wrapped in a `section` but each time there is a short code`[]` this needs to be close and when the content of the short code has been outputted. them open a new `section` and continue with the content from that page.

make sense?
any ideas or help it will be great .. thanks

```
function get_custom_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
    $content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
    $final_cotent = clean_custom_content($content);
    echo $final_cotent;
}
```

**clean_custom_content()::**

```
function clean_custom_content($content){
    if(do_clean_shorcode('someshorty')){
         $content = "<section>".$content.'</section>';
     return $content;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very challenging for generic case since shortcodes can be nested, can be self-closing or enclosing and so on.

If you need to do this on limited and fixed set of *specific* shortcodes that would be easier. I would unregister their shortcode handlers and register custom handlers that call original ones and add necessary markup around.

Comment: Thanks, that was the only way the i could have made work, thanks again for the reply :)